# Sitecore: Display newly created bucketed item

Tags: sitecore

Im using sitecore 8.1 and I have a bucket that accepts a bucketable template. When I right-click the bucket and add an item based on that template, then it gets added to bucket using the default bucket hierarchy (as expected).

The issue is the content editor doesn't display the added item. It in fact displays the parent folder item i.e. /sitecore/content/x/Resources/Document Repository/2016/04/25/20/35

How can I change this so that the added item gets displayed and not its parent?

Thanks

Comment: Supposed your item is A and its template is bucketable. Does the item A appear under the /35?

Answer (score 0):

If viewing buckets is enabled (view tab in the ribbon) then the content editor usually loads the created (bucketable) item. Have you reviewed the log files for possible errors? Have you maybe changed / patched the original Sitecore.Buckets.config file?